# Unable to launch java virtual mchine

Tags: oracle, installation, runtime-error, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having some difficulty installing oracle sql developer.  I downloaded the 64bit/JDK8 combo install from oracle and unzipped it to my downloads folder.  I am running a 64bit version of Windows 10.  From there I tried to run the sqldeveloper.exe.  at this point I get a message saying:

"Unable to launch java virtual machine
Located at
C: /CHMil/downloads/sqldeveloper/jdk/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll."

Now the thing that has made this difficult is when other people have this problem on stack overflow their message says "unable to find" not "lauch".  And their fix is to edit the sqldeveloper.conf and remove the setjavahome line.

My setjavahome line says:
"Setjavahome ../../jdk"

From what I've read this is not what it should look like.  When I try to delete it I get the same message.  If I try to complete the path directly to the jvm.dll.  I get the same message.  And now I have given up getting any help from oracle haha so this is my last shot.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes I am running a 64bit version of Windows, and it is windows 10.

Comment: Newer versions use product.conf rather than sqldeveloper.conf I think, but that setJavaHome looks OK for the bundled version, and you shouldn't need to touch either. If the path to that  exists then it should work. Possibly it can't allocate enough memory, or needs the Java mmx etc. settings to be increased, but the defaults should work.

Comment: Hi Jon. Did you find a way to fix this?